# Git merge error I can not figure out

Tags: git, git-stash

I am newish to Git and ran into an issue I do not understand and can not find in search. I am trying to stash two files that need to be deleted but I can not and I keep getting errors. Latest error below.

```
docroot/sites/all/libraries/wurfl/resources/storage/persistence/1/9/94e44b4e8fd47b34c1646f46907e0e: needs merge
docroot/sites/all/libraries/wurfl/resources/storage/persistence/1/9/94e44b4e8fd47b34c1646f46907e0e: needs merge
docroot/sites/all/libraries/wurfl/resources/storage/persistence/1/9/94e44b4e8fd47b34c1646f46907e0e: unmerged (6f6312822c4d0d0b8ec02807d79da076e3c0db5d)
docroot/sites/all/libraries/wurfl/resources/storage/persistence/1/9/94e44b4e8fd47b34c1646f46907e0e: unmerged (2ae4144909e1c3dce145acc19510a15ac3e09ece)
fatal: git-write-tree: error building trees
Cannot save the current index state
```

How can I stash these because I don't need them? Any help would be awesome!!!
Thanks

Comment: You typed `git merge` and it is in merge conflict mode and you are trying to type `git stash`, or something else??

Comment: I actually pulled in a new branch. We had an outside dev replace a library that was technically not being tracked yet these two files were.

Comment: `git pull` does `git fetch` followed by `git merge`, it looks like the second step put you in conflict mode.  I'd abort the merge, then store off or commit the files and try again.

Comment: You should also add this folder to the .gitignore since you do not need to track your WURFL cache in git.